# Have trouble assigning the id when creating the table dynamically using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[EDIT]**
Thanks for the help from prasad and Vijayp, i solved the the issue of setting up borders.  However, another question is not fully addressed.  I apologized for not making it clear.
My question is that after dynamically created the table. You can see there are 5 horenzontal borders.(Please see picture below)  I want to assign each honrizontal border an id. For instance, I want to assgin the the top border an id of 0; the second top border an id of 1, etc However, I do not know how to do it.  Hope someone could help me out.

[image]

html:

```js
/* js: */

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
     var td1 = document.createElement('td');
     // assign the id
     td1.id = i; 
     tr.appendChild(td1);
     table.appendChild(tr);
     td1.className = "deco";
}
document.body.append(table);
 
});
```

```css
/* css: */

   
.deco {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm.. pretty well defined question.. but the relevant parts need to be clearer.. "[how do I keep the table from shrinking without adding a textNode]" "[how do I] specify ... border in the table" (which is quite easy to lookup). and is the concept of `node.id = ""` doesn't seem relevant to your issue here, so you should probably just included it in your snippet and not mentioned it in your question, eh?

Comment: Hi Brett, thank you for the advice. I just realized that "node.id" question is not fully solved.  I want to assign an id to each horizontal border.  In my picture, there are 6 horizontal border, and I want assign each one of them an id. I might have to redefine the question.

Comment: apart from that.. you have a dependency on jQuery, but you are handling nodes and element initialization and assignment with vanilla javascript.. there's nothing wrong with that, but `$(selector).html()` usage may prove convenient.. and relevant to common patterns..

Comment: Hi Brett, i am going to redefine the question.  Thank you for pointing out the issue.

Comment: @BrettCaswell I am afraid that my question might not draw any attention.  Do you think it is ok (not violating the rules of the community) to ask this question as a new question?

Comment: if you've scoped out another issue, then ask a question relating to that issue... but I would not mutate the current question.. it has answers to it afterall.. a followup question is understandable.. plus, it sounds like a question regarding identifying borders would lead to creative solutions..

Comment: having said that. you should revert your question back to revision 3.. you shouldn't apply the answer/correction into your questions

Comment: Yes, then I will ask the question again.  thank you Brett.

Comment: @vkosyj - could you please tell us what you are going to do after applying `id` to each horizontal border. If everybody is on same page then you may get required solution quickly

Comment: @vijayP he may not mean `hr`.. I think he's thinking to handle CssStyleDeclarations programmatically... but, that's probably for another question..

Comment: Basically, I want 5 straight lines (A to E) and assign each line an id. The way I can think of is to create a table first.  to create 5 straight lines is to create a table.  Then i want to create 5 buttons, when I click buttonA, 5 lines shows up and lineA turns red.  When I click buttonB, another 5 lines shows up(sort of append after the first 5 lines) the line A turns red; If I click buttonA again, another 5 lines show up and line A turns red.. So basically this is what I want and this is why I want to assign each line a id

Comment: I will ask again this question again.  Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: actually @vkosyj I don't want to get you off your current implementation, but you may want to review [XSLTProcessing - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) .. it seems like you're looking to develop a processing method yourself

Comment: i will take a look at it.  Thank you Brett

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**[w3school table](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)**  see the console.log .`id`s are alloted with `td`

***updated***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        //td1.setAttribute("style", "border-bottom: none");
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        table.appendChild(tr);
        td1.id = i;// id placed
        td1.className = "deco";
    }
    document.body.append(table);

      console.log($('table').html())
     
});
```

```css
.deco {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you prasad for helping me.  I do not want character "T" to show up, so why I get rid of the "T" in  var text1 = document.createTextNode('T');  the table collapse.  Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: see the updated snippet. just remove `text1 = document.createTextNode('T');` and apply the padding for `td`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: I just realized that in your solution, it does not assign each horizontal border an id, but assigning each td an id.  I apologize for not making the question clear enough.

Comment: why use like that? without ` border-bottom`.its a cell

Comment: Basically, I want 5 straight lines and assign each line an id. So the way to create 5 straight lines is to create a table.  By the way, in the js code, I want to get access to the td with assigned id 1.  "$('#' + 1).css("border-bottom-color", "#fff");" why the code does not work?  Sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: try like this `$('#' + 1).css("border-bottom-color", "1px solid #fff");"`

Comment: Thank you.  I will try it when I get home since the bus is coming and I don't want to miss it lol

Answer (score 2):

Try to set height and width of `<td>` in following manner:

Height:

```
td1.height = 50;
```

Width:

```
td {
      width: 50px;
}
```

```js
/* js: */

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var text1 = document.createTextNode('');
    td1.appendChild(text1);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    td1.className = "deco";
    td1.height = 50;


  }
  document.body.append(table);

});
```

```css
/* css: */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.deco {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh I see.  Thank you so much.